# How Querying with EDM LINQ Method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How this **LINQ Query syntax**:

```
var city = from c in _db.SubCategories where c.KategorijaID == stateID select new { c.PodKategorijaID, c.NazivPodKategorije };
```

change to **LINQ Method syntax**?

Example

This is **LINQ Query syntax:**

```
    using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    var L2EQuery = from st in context.Students
                   where st.StudentName == "Bill"
                   select st;

    var student = L2EQuery.FirstOrDefault<Student>();
 }
```

and this is **LINQ Method syntax**:

```
  //Querying with LINQ to Entities 
using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    var L2EQuery = context.Students.where(s => s.StudentName == "Bill");

    var student = L2EQuery.FirstOrDefault<Student>();

}
```

Comment: `where select` -> `.Where().Select()`...

Answer (score 1):

```
var city = _db.SubCategories.Where(c => c.KategorijaID == stateID)
                            .Select(c => new { c.PodKategorijaID, c.NazivPodKategorije });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var city = _db.SubCategories.Where(c => c.KategorijaID == stateID)
           .Select(c => new { c.PodKategorijaID, c.NazivPodKategorije });
```